# search with and without a pattern with ag

Tags: shell, grep, ag

With two files with

```
echo 'example.com/call_me?param' > file1.txt
echo 'example.com/call_me_maybe?param' >> file1.txt
echo 'example.com/call_me?' >> file1.txt
echo 'example.com/call_me?param' > file2.txt
echo 'example.com/call_me_maybe?' >> file2.txt

$ ag -v '\?param'
file2.txt
2:example.com/call_me_maybe?

file1.txt
3:example.com/call_me?

$ ag '\/call_me_maybe' -v '\?param'
ERR: Error stat()ing: \?param
ERR: Error opening directory \?param: No such file or directory

$ ag '\/call_me_maybe' -v '\?param' file1.txt
ERR: Error stat()ing: \?param
ERR: Error opening directory \?param: No such file or directory
file1.txt
1:example.com/call_me?param
3:example.com/call_me?
```

I would like to search for one term and exclude the other pattern. Is it possible in one command?

I'm using ag because it digging into `log.gz` files. So I can use `zgrep` or `ag -z`.

Comment: according to the man page, the command line is `ag [options] pattern [path ...]`.  That implies only one pattern.  Have you tried `ag '\/call_me_maybe' | ag -v '\?param` or even `ag '\/call_me_maybe' | grep -v '\?param`?

Comment: I finally did your second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `ag` but according to the man page, the command line is:

```
ag [options] pattern [path ...]
```

That implies only one pattern is allowed.

Just as with `grep` when you want to combine a search with an inverted search (i.e. perform a search for `a AND NOT b`), you can pipe the output into `grep -v ...`.  e.g.

```
ag '\/call_me_maybe' | grep -v '\?param'
```